# Add Event to outlook using event.ics

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, events

Search results webpart gets all the events. We have a display template where we are trying to set the "Add to OutLook" link. Below is the link we are using

```
https://r.sharepoint.com/sites/test/
/US/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=f4a0ca30-d51d-451b-8dac-56be85a60ad8&CacheControl=1&ID=16&Using=event.ics
```

But the problem is that we want the description field to be multi line and rich text box. The default column Comments(Description) is just multi-line and not rich text, how is it possible to make it rich text as well.
Or can you build the link using parameters so that we can pass a custom TestDescrption column which is multi line and rich text  instead of just multi line.

**EDIT 1**
I tried using the below plugin  to add the link and pass data to get the events.
http://addtocalendar.com/?utm_source=tag&utm_medium=go&utm_campaign=tag
Unfortunatly, it does not take in to consideration the `AllDayEvent`, `Recurrent Event` in the options.

**Note**: I am using an item display template to show the results from the events along with the add to `'calendar link'`

Answer (score 1):

See below links

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/67a70245-cd03-48e1-b0fa-71bbb6a7744d/is-enhanced-rich-text-column-supported-by-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95a05ae0-5d3b-432f-81bf-1f4a03e9910b/rich-text-column-in-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy
So in short you can not achieve your requirement using this way. You need to use OpenXML or other tool to create word file programmatically.

You can get some idea from "https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/documentation"

Comment: we are using o365, dont think this will work for it.